# Embedding coffeescript ... in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, embedding

Within the current codebase of javascript code, I would like to be able to incrementally replace functions/blocks using cleaner and compact coffeescript, and add new code using coffeescript.

1. Is it a good practice? (In fact, shouldn't this be a default approach?)
2. I need a utility to convert javascript with embedded coffeescript into javascript, and well integrated into node.js environment?

Comment: Asking whether or not this is good practice is not going to get you a clear answer - the Javascript community is *very* divided on the idea of CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript to Coffee-script two-way [convertor](http://js2coffee.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by "javascript with embedded coffeescript", but nonetheless, here is my advice:

1) Use Grunt to compile your coffeescript into javascript whenever you save a file ( and also have Grunt do other sutff for you )

2) Do all new development in coffeescript.  Once you go coffeescript, you never want to go back.  It's just better, and there really is no downside.

Answer (score -1):

If the objective is to use some language that is concise and to incrementally update your existing Javascript code to that language than Microsoft's TypeScript might be a better choice than CoffeeScript. Typecript lets you mix JavaScript and Typescript.

Comment: This isn't a relevant response to the question. The question is about Coffeescript embedded in native JavaScript. The OP isn't looking for a third option.

Comment: Yes, there is broader question of other candidates for same purpose, i.e. use of more concise, and yet really popular language. But yes, let us retain the focus here.